# Cargar datos en un text box desde sql, al cambiar un combo box o un DataTimePicker en C#, Visual Studio MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server

realizando una aplicación que registra la información diaria de lo que se hizo en una finca durante el día.
La Pantalla es así: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual la intención es que al cambiar un combo box o la fecha del datetimePicker se carguen datos desde sql.

Ya tengo el procedimiento almacenado.
Pero no se como hacer que carguen los datos en c#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo en C#, visual studio:

```
        //Al cambiar la fecha o el combo finca, se ponen los datos si es que hay, en los txt
    private void CargarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca()
    {
        try
        {
            using (GestorDistribucionDiaria laDistribucionDiaria = new GestorDistribucionDiaria())
            {
                int id;
                int.TryParse(cbx_nombreFinca.SelectedValue.ToString(), out id);
                DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_finca.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));


                txt_frutaEstablecida.Text = Convert.ToString(laDistribucionDiaria.ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca(id, fecha));
                txt_atrasoCoyol.Text = Convert.ToString(laDistribucionDiaria.ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca(id, fecha));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error de SQL: " + e.Message);
        }
    }`
```

Este es el codigo que uso para llamar el procedimiento almacenado:

```
//Metodo listar LOTES los textbox, respecto al combo box de la finca y la fecha
    public DataTable ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca(int id_finca, DateTime fecha)
    {
        miComando = new SqlCommand();
        Console.WriteLine(" Gestor ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca");

        miComando.CommandText = "ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca";

        miComando.Parameters.Add("@id_finca", SqlDbType.Int);
        miComando.Parameters["@id_finca"].Value = id_finca;

        miComando.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.Date);
        miComando.Parameters["@fecha"].Value = fecha;

        DataSet laDistribucionDiaria = new DataSet();
        this.abrirConexion();
        laDistribucionDiaria = this.seleccionarInformacion(miComando);
        DataTable miTablaDatos = laDistribucionDiaria.Tables[0];

        return miTablaDatos;
    }
```

Comment: Hola amigo, por favor en vez de usar imágenes puedes colocar el código es mucho mejor para ayudarte.

Comment: Ahí te puse el código. De ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Este codigo no tiene ningun tipo de acceso a base de datos. Donde y como accedes a la base de datos?

Comment: Lo acabo de poner.

Comment: Tienes errores en tu metodo de conexión hacia base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues debes crear la conexión hacia tu `BD` desde `C#`, asumiendo que ya lo hiciste y que el método que agregaste en tu pregunta hace lo que necesitas y lo que deseas es poder invocar dicho método cada vez que cambie un valor de cualquier `control` solo debes agregar estas funciones a los `eventos` de tus controles:

```
private void cbx_nombreFinca_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CargarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void dtp_finca_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CargarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Seleccionas las propiedades del `ComboBox` y en la pestaña eventos buscas `SelectedIndexChanged` ahí asignas el evento, de manera similar haces con el `DateTimePicker`.

Puedes guiarte tienes que hacer algo similar a esto:

```
public DataTable ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca(int id_finca, DateTime fecha)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ListarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_finca", id_finca);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    connection.Close();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Ya hice eso, pero es el método _CargarDistribucionDiariaDatosFinca_  que no funciona, al ejecutar el programa, los datos que me salen es **table** en los campos de texto.

Comment: Que error te da ? Muestra la conexión que realizas hacia tu bd desde c#

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta vela y prueba si funciona estoy desde el celular hice lo que pude

Comment: Muchas gracias Victor, me sirvió!! Pura vida mi amigo.

Comment: De nada amigo, éxitos con tus futuros proyectos.